# How make recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I had made iterative funcion program that count series of: 2/3 + 4/9 + 8/27 + ...
Now i had tried to make recursion function, but i am still confuse to make that because the nominator and denominator are different formula.

My program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i ,sign , p, q, n;
    double x , S;
    S = 0;
    cout << "Insert how many number will be counted : ";
    cin >> n;

    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        p = pow( 2, i );
        q = pow ( 3, i );

        x = ( 1.0 * p / q );
        S = S + x;
    }
    cout << "\nResult : " << S;
}
```

Comment: Forget about C++. Take a piece of plain paper, and a pen, and write down, in logical terms, your proposed approach to implementing this algorithm. Then, [explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck agrees that your proposed solution works, then just simply take what you wrote, in logical terms, and directly translate it into C++ code. Easy.

Comment: Before you make it recursive, you need to make this work and this not working correctly

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double accumulate_seria( size_t n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 
           0.0    : 
           std::pow( 2.0, double( n ) ) / std::pow( 3.0, double( n ) ) + accumulate_seria( n - 1 );
}

int main()
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << accumulate_seria( i ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1: 0.666667
2: 1.11111
3: 1.40741
4: 1.60494
5: 1.73663
6: 1.82442
7: 1.88294
8: 1.92196
9: 1.94798
10: 1.96532
```

Comment: How does this program relates to OP's question?

Comment: @user2807083 The question is "How make recursion in C++"

Comment: Sorry, that horizontal scroller. I don't see the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function if you want recursion:

```
double S(unsigned n, double a=2.0, double b=3.0) {
    if (! n) return 0;

    return a/b + S(--n, a*2, b*3);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
for (unsigned x = 1; x <= 10; ++x)
    std::cout << x << ": " << S(x) << std::endl; // print sum of x elements
```

Output

```
1: 0.666666666667
2: 1.11111111111
3: 1.40740740741
4: 1.6049382716
5: 1.7366255144
6: 1.8244170096
7: 1.88294467307
8: 1.92196311538
9: 1.94797541025
10: 1.96531694017
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is no recursion, just iteration, but IIUC and you want to calculate numerator and denominator based on its previous values, you can change your code this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i ,sign , p, q, n;
    double x , S;
    S = 0;
    cout << "Insert how many number will be counted : ";
    cin >> n;

    p = 1;
    q = 1;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        p *= 2;
        q *= 3;

        x = ( 1.0 * p / q );
        S = S + x;
    }
    cout << "\nResult : " << S;
}
```

Comment: It produce result identical to OP's program, isn't?

Comment: `x = ( 1.0 * p / q );` check this line

Comment: No, it will not. `*` and `/` associates left to right, and first operation will `1.0*p` which gives `double` and than it will divided by q.

Comment: Yes, `1.0 * p` will give double and then you divide by `q` which is an integer

Comment: So and what? `double` diveded by `int` gives `double` again.

Comment: Okay, my bad. just saw `p = 1; q = 1;` It will work just fine. Sorry :)

Comment: @DimChtz: will this work and not the one that you tested before posting and I contradicted?

Comment: @stefaanv I never said your solution won't work (never tested). Both user2807083 and my answer works, probably yours too. In your comment I said I tested mine before posting. not yours

Comment: I didn't even saw your solution

Comment: @DimChtz:I know your solution works, but in your answer, you say that `x = ( 1.0 * p / q );` is a problem.  You don't even answer the OP question.  If that is the reason for your answer, then 'are you sure?' means you think that it is a problem. So you didn't test that the thing you thought is a problem, is actually a problem.

Comment: I think @stefaanv means that your answer is not answer at all, because it fixes problem which is not existent.

Comment: @user2807083 Well in that case, same applies to your answer, you just replaced the `pow`

Comment: I explicitly explain what I mean to op and now waiting for his reaction. I think maybe op poorly explain what he want.

Comment: @user2807083 thanks for your answer, now i am still confused to convert become recursion. Should i make two function ( numerator ) and ( denomintor )